# How to add selected customer image in Odoo POS v12

Tags: odoo-12

I'd like to add the selected customer image on the left of his name and replace the fa-user icon.
I've tried to use

```
<t t-if='widget.pos.get_client().image'>
    <img t-att-src='widget.pos.get_client().image' alt="widget.pos.get_client()"/>
</t>
```

with "widget.pos.get_client().image" to call image in pos.xml and declare it in  model.js

```
get_image: function() {
    return this.image;
},
```

but image value is always null.

Does anyone know how to get the selected customer image ?

thx for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JS //

```
screens.ActionpadWidget.include({
        partner_icon_url: function(id){
             return '/web/image?model=res.partner&id='+id+'&field=image_small';
    },
    });
```

In XML //
inherit the view and this line.

```
<t t-extend="ActionpadWidget">
        <t t-jquery="i[class='fa fa-user']" t-operation="replace">
             <div class='client-picture' style="height: 50px;width: 50px;">
                <img t-att-src='widget.partner_icon_url(partner.id)' alt="Partner logo"/>
            </div>
        </t>

</t>
```